# Change tooltip background in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am running Ubuntu 10.10. The java docs tooltip that pops up when hovering around a keyword in Eclipse IDE is white on a black background. I need to change the background to some light color that is easy on the eye. But unfortunately there is no such option in the IDE settings. After some searching, I found out that it takes the colors from the Ubuntu system theme. Is there anyway to change the Ubuntu tooltip background color (i.e the color of the tooltip when you hover around the main menu) alone retaining the other schemes of the default theme.

Comment: 2016 and Eclipse still does this ****

Answer (score 11, accepted):

System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colors -> Tooltips

Go on and change the colors at will.

Comment: You may wish to note that some themes don't allow you to customize the custom screen through the Appearance capplet; in that case, you'll either have to switch themes or edit the theme manually.

Comment: In Lubuntu, go to Preferences, Look and Feel, then the Color tab, and change the tooltip colours there.

Comment: You may need to restart eclipse to see the effect.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse:

Window->Preferences->Java->Editor

Here, there is the Source hover background color option. Uncheck System Default, and set any color you would like as a background.

Comment: For me, this only changes the background when hovering over a collapsed code piece's `(+)`, not the javadoc, but it's a good hint!

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to change System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colors -> Selected Items.

This is what prevented white text on white Background in Eclipse for me.

Comment: Perfect! This was the issue that led me to this question from the start! Thanks!